# ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC - generate pop up message in controller

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, model-view-controller

I don't really have an idea how to handle it.

Idea is simple: user presses next page button, but returned data is empty, which means previous page was the last one. User is redirected to current page (last one with data) so they won't go too far, but I want to inform them why they can't go further.

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index(int page = 1)
        {
            var data = new List<DataModel>();

            page = page < 1 ? 1 : page;
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;

            try
            {
                var data = ...get data...

                if (data.Count == 0 && page > 1)
                {
                    //declare pop up message
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { page = page - 1 });                  
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
            }
            return View(data);
        }
```

I tried some googling but it looks like troublesome task, and even if it works in one browser, it won't work in the other. I don't expect that you will do this for me, but I would like some guidance which solution is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to define a custom parameter in your `Index` method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index(int page = 1, bool isLastPage = false) {
 /* ... */
}
```

Now by default this is false. Now you can check, whether it is true and set your ViewModel or ViewBag/Data flag accordingly:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index(int page = 1)
{
    var data = new List<DataModel>();

    page = page < 1 ? 1 : page;
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
    //pass flag to view here
    ViewBag.IsLastPage = isLastPage;

    try
    {
        var data = ...get data...

        if (data.Count == 0 && page > 1)
        {
            //declare pop up message
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { page = page - 1, isLastPage = true });                  
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }
    return View(data);
}
```

In your `RedirectToAction` call you set your flag to true, so in the redirect it will be triggered.

Comment: I feel like you can just throw something to ViewBag in `if` statement, but I still don't know how to generate pop up message.

Comment: Thats a frontend problem. Use `@if((bool)ViewBag.IsLastPage == true) { <div>Popup here </div> }
})`. Hoever, how you actually do a popup is an html specific issue. It could be a simple javascript alert or a more sophisticated react/vue/bootstrap component

Comment: Guess I'll search for some javascript alterts then.